# Java - non-generic class extends generic class

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance

I would like to know how (if possible) can I create a class, that is a specific type of a generic class.

To be specific, I have an `abstract class Stack<Type>` with all necessary methods implemented and I would like to have a `class StackInteger` while an instance of `StackInteger` is also an instance of `Stack<Integer>`.

I see I can do something like this:

```
class StackInteger {
    Stack<Integer> s;

    public StackInteger(int size) {
        s = new Stack<Integer>(size);
    }

}
```

and then implement all *Stack* methods to contain `s.method();` but I wonder if I can do it easily while extending from *Stack*.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're wanting to do this? From the example you gave, all you're doing is masking `Stack<Integer>` with two fewer characters...

Comment: Then I can have for example StackInteger and StackString which both implements it's own methods but have the Stack functionality in common.

Comment: @dannymo the problem is that if you need to process just a Stack i.e. common processing to both a StackString and a StackInteger, then you wouldn't be able to do it, because a StackString is not a StackInteger.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in this case, inheritance is a better solution than composition as you have it, because a `StackInteger` is a `Stack`.

Just supply `Integer` as a type argument in the `extends` clause.

```
class StackInteger extends Stack<Integer>
```

However, if you don't supply any additional functionality beyond what `Stack` already has, then this class is useless and you might as well just use `Stack<Integer>`.

Comment: Additionally if you do need to use `Stack<Integer>` then prefer the equivalent `Deque` implementation as it provides a more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02216/

Comment: It works as expected when I do `StackInteger st = new StackInteger(3);` however when I do `Stack st = new StackInteger(3);` I can push whatever type in the stack with no problem. Why is that possible when `st` is instance of StackInteger so it is instanceof Stack<Integer> even that the pointer is only a Stack?

Comment: That is because you are using the _raw_ form of the `Stack` class.  Type erasure occurs, and `T` becomes `Object` (the upper bound).  Instead, use `Stack<Integer> st = new StackInteger(3);`.

Comment: @dannymo, read item 23 Don't use raw types in new code, in Effective Java.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's the correct answer to a factual question.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Most likely it was Magnamag.  I saw that user's reputation, as displayed on this question, decline from 2135 to 2133 after our answers were downvoted.

Comment: @rgettman yes it was me. Sorry. It's just that I think it's not a good answer. As I said in my answer and as Brian Goetz explains in the article I provided a link to, extending from a generic type to mask type information is an antipatterm. Actually,  a quite bad one.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against extending generic classes just to overcome generics verbosity. This is an antipattern, known as the [**pseudo-typedef antipattern**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02216/).

From the article:

> if a method parameter is of type StringList, you cannot pass an ordinary List to it. This means that you cannot use pseudotypes at all as method arguments without requiring that every use of that method use the pseudotype, which in practicality means that you cannot use pseudotypes at all in library APIs.

...

> A further problem with the pseudo-typedef antipattern is that it tends to ignore the benefit of using interfaces to define the types of variables and method arguments. While it is possible to define StringList as an interface that extends List and a concrete type StringArrayList that extends ArrayList and implements StringList, most users of the pseudo-typedef antipattern generally do not go to this length, as the purpose of this technique is primarily to simplify and shorten type names. As a result, APIs will be less useful and more brittle because they use concrete types like ArrayList rather than abstract types like List.

So, why not sticking to `Stack<Integer>`? I don't think it's so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

```
class StackInteger extends Stack<Integer> {
    ....
}
```

As @Magnamag points out, this is often considered an antipattern. This is especially true if it is done just to avoid having to specify type parameters.

However, there can be legitimate ways to do this. For example, if the non-generic class is `private`, users of the class will be forced to program to the interface (or abstract class) anyway. In this example (admittedly rather contrived), there is a static method returning a non-generic anonymous class extending `AbstractList<String>`.

```
public class Main  {

    public static List<String> helloWorld() {
        return new AbstractList<String>() {
            @Override
            public String get(int i) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0: return "Hello";
                    case 1: return "World";
                    default: throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public int size() {
                return 2;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(helloWorld());
    } 
}
```